# Signs of terms when expanding using the distributive property

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, arithmetic

I would like to ask a question that might seem ridiculous but I'm really willing to comprehend the what and why rather than simply memorizing some rule or pattern that applies "the best". And I hope it will help other people who have similar question.

So, the issue is as follows: **I'm always getting confused when expanding or simplifying an expression when it comes to the signs of its terms**.

Let's take this expression for example:

$$4(x^2 + 3x - 5)$$

I get 3 possible scenarios in my mind:

**SOLUTION#1**: I have to multiply each term by factor of 4 WITHOUT looking at their signs. It goes like:

initial expression: $$4(x^2 + 3x - 5)$$
expanding: $$(4 * x^2) + (4 * 3x) - (4 * 5)$$
result: $$4x^2 + 12x - 20$$

I didn't take into account the plus and minus signs standing close to the numbers when multiplying them by 4. Rather, I left them there as it was in the initial expression as if this group in parentheses didn't know about distribution (if I can say so).

**SOLUTION#2**: I have to multiply each term by factor of 4 WITH their signs taken into account. It goes like (this approach might hurt your eyes and perhaps the common sense (if it wasn't hurt by the very question already) so I apologize in advance):

initial expression: $$4(x^2 + 3x - 5)$$
distributing to the first term: $$(4 * (+x^2)) = + 4x^2$$
distributing to the second term: $$(4 * (+3x)) = + 12x$$
distributing to the third term: $$(4 * (-5)) = - 20$$
so we get: $$4x^2 + 12x - 20$$

**SOLUTION#3**: Most of the times I used to solve it this way:

initial expression: $$4(x^2 + 3x - 5)$$
expanding: $$(4 * x^2) + (4 * 3x) - (4 * (-5))$$
then I would get: $$4x^2 + 12x - (-20)$$
And here's where I would get completely stuck as to if I should leave it as is OR make it like this:
$$4x^2 + 12x + 20$$

I know that SOLUTION#3 is a result of the lack of knowledge and confusion between different rules.

SOLUTION#1 and SOLUTION#2 yield the correct answers though.

Could anyone please explain which of these solutions is correct and must be applied?

Or both of the first solutions are correct and might be used interchangeably?

Or none of them actually make sense?

**UPD**: I guess that my problem is that I can't differentiate when signs indicate some operation or they belong to some number and indicate that it's positive or negative. I'm used to view plus and minus signs as indicators of both operations and that number is positive or negative. And it results into confusion like in SOLUTION#3.

Comment: When learning about group theory, which in some sense gives axioms to understand binary laws like addition or multiplication, one understands that the "correct" way to see the symbol $-$ is as a minus sign, and not as an operation - which it is not. In an abelian group for instance, $-x$ is defined as the unique element such that $x + (-x) = 0$. Since it is clumsy to write parentheses everywhere, we alleviate the notations by allowing ourselves to write $x - y$ instead of $x + (-y)$. Now, in a ring, which is like an abelian group equipped with a multiplication [...]

Comment: [...] there are axioms to describe compatibility between addition and multiplication. Among these rules is distributivity, which says that $x(y+z) = xy + xz$. This rule implies that $-(xy) = x(-y) = (-x)y$. Indeed, $-(xy)$ is the unique element $z$ such that $xy + z = 0$. But we have $0 = x*0 = x(y-y) = x(y+(-y)) = xy + x(-y)$. Thus, we obtain $-xy = x(-y)$ by unicity. This shows that the different rules you are using in solution 1 and 2 are compatible, and this follows from general axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions $1$ and $2$ would be the best path to take.

Solution #$1$ uses the distributive property by using all positive numbers and then using the operations in sequence, i.e. $4(x^2 + 3x - 5) = 4\cdot x^2 + 4 \cdot 3 x - \color{red}{({4 \cdot 5)}} = 4x^2 + 12x - 20.$

Solution #$2$ uses the distributive property by multiplying each of the numbers according to the signs, and any negative values become minus signs, i.e. $4(x^2 + 3x - 5) = +4\cdot (+1x^2) + +4 \cdot (+3x) + \color {blue}{({+4\cdot -5)}}= 4x^2 + 12x - 20.$

The problem with solution #$3$ is that there is an extra minus sign added before $5$, and while $(-4) \cdot (-5) = +20$, it produces the incorrect answer $4x^2 + 12x + 20$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! So as I see it's fine to use both Solutions #1 and #2. But are those solutions backed up by some rules from abstract math or anything else? Or we're simply deducing it on the go? I'm really interested in getting very deep into some fundamental rules of math so that I could explain why everyone does it exactly this way and not another one. 
I just feel like I shouldn't get even into the pre-algebra realm before I learn the very core and abstract concepts of math

Comment: You're welcome!

In a nutshell, the rules themselves come from abstract algebra (e.g. groups and rings) but those concepts are molded to their respective audiences.  For those learning pre-algebra here in America, a textbook might state, "the reasons for this are beyond the scope of this book," but further along in academic learning, some may take those courses to discover why $(-a)(-b) = +(ab)$ from a more abstract point of view.